Outlook: Finding messages containing a specific version number in the message subject seems broken
It seems search ion Outlook 2019 (from Office Professional Plus) on Windows 10 is completely broken, or terribly documented:
I had messages created automatically, and I wanted to clean up some of those.
Fortunately they have a version number in the subject like "vX.Y.Z", so I just tried to match a specific version (to mark and delete all the matching messages).
However when searching for v1.1.1 Outlook also matched v1.4.0 and others.
I fail to understand.
Putting the search string in double-quotes did not help.
I had tried both, quick search and extended search with no differences in the result.
Example
Searching for "v1.1.1", a message with the subject line pw-expiration/LPE/v1.4.0: Password Expiration... was matched, as well as  the subject pw-expiration/LPE/v1.3.1: Password Expiration... and pw-expiration/LPE/v1.2.0: Password Expiration....

Note: Outlook opened the search pull-down when I had activated the snipping tool, but when the search results had been shown, the pull-down list had been collapsed
(I added yellow markups in snipping tool for illustration).
For example this is a literal subject line from a matching message (German):
Subject: pw-expiration/LPE/v1.4.0: Passwortablauf von testuser vor 4.456
 Tagen

However when I entered "v1.4" as search string, "v1.4" was highlighted in the search results, but still other subject lines were listed where the string did not occur.

When I entered "v.1.1" instead, no results were found (which is correct).
So what's going on?
Another completely broken product from the market leader?

Sounds like search interprets a 1 as any digit from 0 to 9''... I suggest you look up search help, and check if it can use pattern matching

It seems that Outlook search is as useless as it seems:
According to the How to search in Outlook document:

Punctuation is ignored in the search box. Entering “Spring Planning Meeting.” is the same as entering “Spring Planning Meeting.”

Strings of numbers less than five digits are ignored. If you want to search for 98101, entering 9810 will not return any results.


Given the lack of escaping and quoting this essentially means that you cannot search for version numbers in the subject.
